# Generating tuples using list comprehension

Tags: haskell

I generate tuples using list comprehension:

```
[(a,b,c) | a <- [1..3], b <- [1..3], c <- [1..3]]
```

Since all three entries of the tuples are from the same interval, is there a shorter way to write this?

Comment: Keeping it in the comprehension `[(a,b,c)| p<-[[1..3]], a<-p,b<-p,c<-p]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few alternatives

```
let xs = [1..3] in [(a,b,c) | a <- xs, b <- xs, c <- xs]
[(a,b,c) | let xs = [1..3], a <- xs, b <- xs, c <- xs]
(,,) <$> [1..3] <*> [1..3] <*> [1..3]
let xs = [1..3] in (,,) <$> xs <*> xs <*> xs
(\[a,b,c]->(a,b,c)) <$> replicateM 3 [1..3]
```

However, I'd look for the most readable one, rather than the shortest.

Comment: I like the comprehension with `let` and `(,,) <$> xs <*> xs <*> xs` = `liftA3 (,,) xs xs xs` the most. Another needlessly clever trick is to use the `(->)` applicative and list applicative together to make a point-free version, `join (join (liftA3 (,,))) [1..3]`.